# Importing module that didn't exist build time

Tags: import, webpack, require

With Webpack, can I `require('file.js')` that didn't exist build/bundle time? I know all about alternative solutions to solve this, I need a way to do `require/import` specifically.

Comment: What is your use case? Why does the file not exist during build time?

Comment: @MarioTacke There are some secrets that need to be in prod build, but there is no access to them during build time. And the app is just a static html/js. File with secrets is being copied to www after deploy.

Comment: I hope you are not serving your app with the secrets to the clients. Webpack creates browser bundles which usually execute *on* the client, even in production. If you still want to follow this approach, you can require the secret file during your production build in, for example, a CI environment, or make it a process environment variable on the production server. There are usually better ways to handle secrets than serving them to the client. Consider editing your question with mock code/secrets for us to better understand your current process.

Comment: Not that kind of secrets, this is merely an attempt to hide test/staging urls.

Comment: I admit 'secrets' is a smelly choice of word

Comment: Okay that sounds much less severe. :) You can define a global variable in webpack with the DefinePlugin. For example, it is very common to include the node process NODE_ENV and then evaluate on the client which url to go with. If you are interested, I can answer your question with an example.

Comment: And my question is exactly how i described it. I want to know how can i require file that was added to the build later.

Comment: I can't use env vars (don't ask :) )

Comment: Again - i don't need an alternative solution, there are plenty, thanks for willingness to help. It made me curious if i can do this particular thing i described in the question.

Comment: The answer to that would be "no". Requires are bundled into a single file. The browser does not have access to disk.

Comment: Well browser can make XHR and webpack compatible files could be wrapped in some kind of boilerplate.

Comment: So, if i would to add such a feature to webpack, i'd say structure your files like `initWebpackModule(()=>{//your code here})` and then call `require.external('file.js', callback)` to asynchronously load the dependency